# Problem regarding the sign of the first derivative of a $C^1$ function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x):(1,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function, such that

$$ (\forall x^{\in(1,\infty)}):f^\prime(x)=\frac{x^2-f^2(x)}{x^2(f^2(x)+1)}.$$

Now, if $f(x)>x$, then $f^2(x)>x^2$ (since $x\in(1,\infty)$), therefore the sign of the first derivative would be negative, hence $f(x)$ would be a strictly decreasing function on the mentioned domain.

Does this imply that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=-\infty$, or am I missing something?

Comment: a function could be strictly decreasing and not approach $-\infty$, e.g., $\exp(-x)$

Comment: You can't have a strictly decreasing function $f$ such that $f(x)>x$ for all $x \in (1,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I just saw a solution for the converse, i.e. the derivative property holds and if $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in(1,\infty)$. Then the conclusion that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ clearly holds, but I don't see why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\dfrac1x$, or $f(x)=\dfrac1{\ln x}$, or the example @J W Tanner gave ($f(x)=e^{-x}$).  How about $f(x)=\dfrac1{x^2}$. Or, well, there's plenty of counterexamples...

Comment: Yup, thanks for the answer!